# Adding an inline keyboard after editing message

Tags: python-2.7, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have this piece of code for a button which edits a message on Telegram.

```
def startbutton(bot, update):   
    query = update.callback_query        
    toss_keyboard = [[  InlineKeyboardButton("1", callback_data='1'),
                        InlineKeyboardButton("2", callback_data='2'),
                        InlineKeyboardButton("3", callback_data='3'),
                        InlineKeyboardButton("4", callback_data='4'),
                        InlineKeyboardButton("5", callback_data='5'),
                        InlineKeyboardButton("6", callback_data='6')
                    ]]

    toss_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(toss_keyboard)
    bot.edit_message_text(text="Click on any of the buttons below:", chat_id=None,message_id=None, inline_message_id = query.inline_message_id)
```

The message gets edited perfectly fine, but I want to add the above toss_keyboard(6 buttons) after the message is edited in the SAME message.How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `reply_markup=toss_keyboard` to the `edit_message_text`. The previous answer is wrong. `edit_message_text` can edit the text PLUS the reply markup in one call, yet `edit_reply_markup` only edits the keyboard.

By the way you can use this shortcut to reduce redundant info in the edit call: `query.message.edit_text("new text", reply_markup=some_new_markup)`

Answer (score 0):

As you can find at [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages), you can edit message text, message caption or reply markup at one time. Because of your message didn't have an inline keyboard, you can't add it while editing (there was no keyboard -> no way to edit *nothing*, I hope you get me). So, you have to create keyboard first, only after that you can edit it.